# MySql on Mac/Maverics and the disappearing databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, osx-mavericks

So, I have this problem and no one seems to be able to figure out what is going on.

I have MySql server installed on my MBA using Mavericks 10.9.4 and have both Sequel Pro and Workbench for playing with the databases. But from time to time, after I've created and built a database, made queries, commited and saved outputs and queries, the databases disappear. I can recreate the instance if I crash my computer but still having committed the last query or view or what'have'you.

Example: My MBA runs out of juice and powers down or something makes me have to crash and reboot the computer. I then run the MySql server and e.g. Sequel to continue my work. Sequel "sees" the database, all it's tables and even views but when I click a table I get this error message:

**An error occurred while retrieving the information for table 'People'. Please try again.
MySQL said: Table 'p1.people' doesn't exist**

I then try to fill the tables again with my data (#teambackupyourwork) and get this error message:

`[ERROR in query 2] Table 'p1.gender' doesn't exist`

I then try to drop the tables and the database which doesn't seem to exist but is still visible and get this error message:

`Error dropping database (can't rmdir './p1', errno: 66)`

I therefore have to sudo rm -rf the f*cking database to be able to redo everything.

First I thought that this was to do with some über-forgiving preferences in the Clean My Mac 2 program so I poked and prodded around and now it almost only uninstalls programs and takes out the trash.

So, I have to create the database EACH AND EVERY DAY! My professor has tried his best, asking me to commit before intentionally crashing and rebooting and nothing seems to work.

This has gone on now since the beginning of school and I'm getting pretty frustrated.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

look at your Mysql configuration, it may store your data in temporary folders. Have seen similar issues with postgresql installed on MBP.

The fix for my problem was to reinstall postgresql using homebrew.

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't a good idea to try this at 4 in the morning. I've successfully installed and uninstalled both homebrew and for some reason Ruby as well because the sh*t hit the fan when I had this installed. The server didn't work, mysql wasn't an authorized user and I couldn't connect to mysql and therefore nothing worked. So, I'm back to where I started but still able to create the same database each day and able to turn in homework assignments based on that database. It sucks but it beats the alternative.

Thanks for the help though, I appreciate it!

Comment: When you do this with homebrew - you have to run additional tasks to configure your user: simply look at this http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysql-change-root-password/

Comment: Ok, thanks for the additional info. I'll try this out as soon as I've turned in this week's assignment.